# Copy one table record to another in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a **User** model and  **users** table. A user can have many phone numbers so I have a separate Model  named `Phone`.
I am using this association for that:

**Model**

```
User
     attr_accessible :id, :name, :screenname,:fullname,:phones_attributes
     has_many :phones,:dependent => :destroy

Phone
     attr_accessible :phone
     belongs to :users
```

Above code works fine. 
  Admin want to copy any user's record into `user_temp` and `phone_temp` table as well (I have separate models named **UserTemp** and **PhoneTemp**).

How can I do this?

Comment: do you have another model for user_temp and phone-temp

Comment: Yes, As i have mention above.

Comment: yes both the below solutions will work for you :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest way would be:

```
phone_item = Phone.find(x)   # Get the phone item you want to copy
                             # you may have obtained this some other way

PhoneTemp.create(phone_item.attributes) if phone_item
```

Similarly for the User.

Comment: I know this is old, but you're doing both a create and a save. You probably meant `.new(...).save` or just `.create(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have separate model for temp_user then you can so something like this

```
@user = User.find(params[:id]) # find original object
@temp_user = TempUser.create(@user.attributes)
```